# In angular 9 Do I need to configure interceptor for each new http client separately?

Tags: angular

I know how interceptor works. Usually what we do is inject httpClient inside the constructor by dependency injection so every time we are using the same instance. I want to know how interceptor works actually in case of multiple httpClient instance.

Let's say we created two angular http client,

```
client1=new HttpClient();
this.client1.get<CustomObject>(this.baseUrl + "Customer/Get?pCustomerId=" + pId, options);

client2=new HttpClient();
this.client2.get<CustomObject>(this.baseUrl + "Customer/Get?pCustomerId=" + pId, options);
```

Let say, we created an interceptor "**interceptor1**"

Do I need to explicitly tell client1/client2 which interceptor it needs to use while making the request? Or interceptor is independent from client and it doesn't distinguish from which client the request was originated?

Comment: First of all the way you create new HttpClient() is not right way to do. First of all You need to import `HttpClientModule` inside app.module.ts once. and all interceptors are provided with app.module.ts. and inside any module in your application when you inject HttpClient, it will go through global interceptors

Comment: For Lazy loading module, if you re import `HttpClientModule` in lazy module, then it will not going through global interceptors provided with app.module.ts, because lazy module creates new injector and re importing HttpClientModule again, it will create new instance for httpClient for that lazy module and it will have two different httpClient instance inside application